# Getting the Next record when joining to table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wanting to join a table that contains co-borrower information to a primary borrower information. The data seems to be inaccurate at points. What I'm seeing is that sometimes the Primary Borrower is also a co-borrower. This shouldn't be happening.

I want to select the next co-borrower if the primary and secondary social Security # match.

This is what I basically have have:

```
Select a.PrimaryBorrower
,a.Accountnumber
,a.PriamrySSN
,b.SecondarySSN
from  Primarytable A
Left Join Secondarytable B
 on a.accountnumber = B.accountnumber and 
 b.secondaryssn != A.primarySSN
```

I know this won't work, but i'm not entirely sure how i should go about doing this.

```
Primaryssn | AccountNumber | Primaryborrower 
  xxxx1       123               AB
  XXXX2       134               BC
SecondarySSN | Accountnumber | SeondaryBorrower 
  xxxx1         123              AB
  xxxx3         123              CB
  xxxx5         134              RC
  XXXX9         123              ZB
```

and what i want to get as a result is:

```
 PrimaryBorrower | Accountnumber |PrimarySSN | SecondarySSN
     AB                 123          xxxx1      xxxx3
     BC                 134          XXXX2      XXXX5
```

Comment: Account 123 has two secondary borrowers.  How is "3" chosen?

Comment: you should also consider accepting answers on your previous questions that you let go stale without feedback. @GordonLinoff answered the last three...

Comment: @gordonlinoff, this was the problem that i was having. My goal was to get the primary and secondary borrowers. However the data is not clean and people entered the primary as the secondary as well. I wanted to get the next borrower where the SSN numbers did not match. Just the next ONE.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff and scsimon. I hadn't realized that the checkmark next to the answers indicate the answer that worked for me. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close, just a small tweak to arbitrarily choose the secondary borrower with the lowest SSN.

```
WITH cteRowNums AS (
    Select a.PrimaryBorrower
          ,a.Accountnumber
          ,a.PriamrySSN
          ,b.SecondarySSN
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.Accountnumber ORDER BY b.SecondarySSN) AS RowNum
        from  Primarytable A
            Left Join Secondarytable B
                on a.accountnumber = B.accountnumber 
                    and  b.secondaryssn != A.primarySSN 
)
SELECT PrimaryBorrower
      ,Accountnumber
      ,PriamrySSN
      ,SecondarySSN
    FROM cteRowNums
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: @WWaldo Great! As commented on your question above, please accept the answers that have worked for you.